# How to Search for question in Close Votes

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close

How to Search for a question in Close Votes in Review section.

The below question is voted to close with a wrong question. How can we find  this question in [Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close) in review and reject the close vote

**Question :** [Oracle : How to delete duplicates rows when no distinct value exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521260/oracle-how-to-delete-duplicates-rows-when-no-distinct-value-exists)

The above question is closed as duplicate with this [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql) which is of `Mysql` TAG where as the original question is asked for `Oracle`

Comment: Do you have a better dupe for that Oracle question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go to the question [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35521260/timeline) and look for the orange review category. Click the [close](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/11339638) link

[image: timeline of question]

Notice that there isn't a direct link to the timeline view. You have to fiddle it in the address bar of your browser to go from

> `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521260`

to

> `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35521260/timeline`

If the review is completed the [entry is no longer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/275795/158100) but you (as a > 10K-er) can use the userscript I created [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35521260/timeline)

If you're interested, there are more *[hidden features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-exchange)*...

Comment: Wow, That is good to know

Comment: How you got that timeline link. Is it present somewhere in question

Comment: Hand crafted @VR46

Comment: Sick work man!!. How you know all these hidden features simply you guys are insane :)

Comment: @VR46 I guess it shows I have no life or I hang around in the right chatrooms. Also on MSE a lot of this stuff is documented.